# Is there a type of collection or associative-array where the key is also and/or part of the value?

Tags: c#, collections, associative-array

I'm working on a map for a Roguelike, and each cell of the map is accessed through a dictionary<sup>[1]</sup>, with the key being a custom struct `Axis3`, which just stores an integer location on 3 axes. The issue is, the cell itself also needs to keep track of its position, and this leads to a duplication of data. In this particular example, it isn't a lot of additional memory (`3 MB` for the active area, `~60 MB` for the map area kept in memory but not currently being calculated), but it exposes an issue that I feel should be solved if possible (especially since cells aren't the only objects that key themselves in collections based on their position).

I'm working in [unity](/questions/tagged/unity), and thus have so far looked at options directly available in .NET 3.5 and outside implementations compatible with such, but haven't had any luck in finding a collection where the key is part of or is the value. `HashSet` would actually work perfectly for what I want (simply make `Axis3` and `Cell` with the same position equate to equal), but there is no way to retrieve the original reference without iterating the set.

I've also looked into `KeyedCollection`, but it doesn't appear to reference the key inside of the value, instead copying the key from the value and inserting it into a separate collection for lookup purposes, which would make `KeyedCollection` actually worse for memory footprint.

[1] For the curious, this is done instead of an array, because not every z-level or even every layer (terrain, items, enemies, etc.) in each z-level is filled, so using a dictionary allows for a much smaller memory footprint while still having fast access, as long as missing cells are treated as a default value (much the same way as a sparse array). It also has other benefits that aren't worth getting into here.

Comment: Is the usage of `struct` (value types) mandatory ?

Comment: @quantdev No, the struct could just as easily be a class. `Axis3` generally belongs to an object though or exists in relation to an object, and being as small as it is, it makes more sense structurally (no pun intended) to be a struct. It also simplifies (and reduces the chance of bugs) the accessors for the position of objects, as you don't need to explicitly copy the `Axis3` when it's a struct. Even objects at the same position shouldn't share the same reference, due to the likelihood of them moving.

Comment: Having a reference type would avoid any copy of the object in the key. Does that make sense ?

Comment: @quantdev Absolutely; storing a reference obviously avoids copying the referenced data at the cost of a dereference on access. The real issue though is that an `Axis3` represents an atomic value (in the sense that it can't be further reduced, not threading wise) as far as the map is concerned, and really shouldn't be passed around by reference except internally such as within a collection.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, I'm not aware of anything suitable (although I mostly use Java rather than C#).

The problem is that in order to store the key into the value you need to have a place to store the key in the value. That means that objects being added into the collection need to have suitable storage in place or you need to create a "wrapper" object that does have that storage and the values in the map become the wrapper object.

You could create a collection to give you the behavior you need but a better way to handle this by having the architecture of your objects correct.

Have the coordinates as an immutable object. The map then becomes a map of the co-ordinates to the object. The object also stores the reference to the co-ordinates.

The code that moves the object should exist in one place and it should both update the reference in the object and move the object in the map as one step. You might need to consider thread synchronization as well for safety here.

Yes, unfortunately in a way this is duplicated data but sometimes that is unavoidable. You want to be able to follow the link in both directions, in order to do that efficiently you need the link to exist in both directions.

The key here is to make it impossible for someone to accidentally change one of these links without also changing the other.